# Javascript permission denied - different port

Tags: javascript, iframe, permissions

I have a rails app running on port 3000. The page in question has an iframe and I need to resize it depending on the height of the content loaded in the iframe.

```
<iframe id="ifrm_col3" name="ifrm_col3" frameborder="0" 
src="<%=invite_path(@invite.alias)%>" 
onload="util.resize_iframe('ifrm_col3');"></iframe>
```

The resize function is here:

```
util.resize_iframe = function(frame_id) {
  var h = document.getElementById(frame_id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
  document.getElementById(frame_id).height = h; 
}
```

After the iframe loads, I see this error in FireBug:

```
Error: Permission denied for <http://192.168.0.157> to get property Window.document from <http://192.168.0.157:3000>.
Source File: http://192.168.0.157:3000/javascripts/application.js?1268327481
Line: 84
```

HTML rendered for the iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe id="ifrm_col3" name="ifrm_col3" frameborder="0" 
            src="/invite/my-invite-1" 
            onload="util.resize_iframe('ifrm_col3');"></iframe>
```

The src of iframe is a relative path, but I'm not sure why the port info from the parent page is not retained. Is there any workaround to this problem?

I tried creating a function in the parent page and calling it from the iframe, but ran into the same issue.

Due to extra features in the site, I need to stick to port 3000 for the rails app.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you quite sure that `<%=invite_path(@invite.alias)%>` does, in fact, output a relative path? That nothing has resolved it (incorrectly) along the way? What does the actual output to the `src` attribute end up looking like?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, thanks for the reply. Yes, I updated the post with HTML snippet.

Comment: @Grnbeagle: I can't see any reason the browser should be (mis)interpreting that as being on port 80 instead of 3000, provided the page the iframe is in is served via port 3000.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, you're right. This shouldn't happen. It's my bad. The page in the question uses a stomp client library which requires to set document.domain. I'm doing research on how to get around it. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @Gmbeagle: `document.domain` -- why didn't I think of that?! Good luck with it.